# Discrepancy between Mobile and Desktop Answer Count

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

On the Desktop, the "Answer Count" will include deleted questions. Meaning that [this Sandbox question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3129/11811) with only 3 non-deleted answers will have an Answer Count of 69:

[image: Desktop Answer Count]

However, on Mobile, only non-deleted answers are counted. So the answer count will be 3:

[image: Mobile Answer Count]

I'm fine with either functionality, but can we make this consistent?

*Repro with*
**Desktop:** Google Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)
**Mobile:** iOS 12.1.4 Safari